# What is a good strategy to fix up a lawn in winter?

Tags: lawn, lawn-repair, dryness

I have an issue with my lawn.

[image: issue]

There is a huge patch of dead grass just below a covered area. The area gets plenty of sun, but I guess it just does not get enough water.

What is a good strategy to fix this ugliness now that **winter** just started?

1. Should I bother fertilizing the dead area?
2. Should I buy a few more rolls of grass?
3. Should I add top soil?
4. Should I invest in a sprinkler system for the dead area, if so what?
5. What about de-thatching?

Comment: also: climate is temperate with mild winters (Sydney Australia), lawn is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sir_Walter_Buffalo_Turf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

However drought-resistant the variety of grass, it will need *some* water, and clearly this patch below the covered area has received virtually none, hence the problem; so, unless you are prepared for the backache involved in watering it manually, you will have to buy a sprinkler. As I don't have one myself, I can't recommend one, but there are plenty of inexpensive sprinklers for sale on eBay, Australia, [here](http://shop.ebay.com.au/?_from=R40&_trksid=p3907.m570.l1311&_nkw=garden%20sprinkler&_sacat=See-All-Categories), which should fit the bill. Re-seeding is not an option in winter, because the soil isn't warm enough, so I suggest you:

1. Square off the area around the patch;
2. Remove the thatch and the grass around it;
3. Break up the soil to a depth of about 12- 15";
4. Add a little topsoil;
5. Apply a good fertilizer (such as Growmore  - 2 oz per sq yard);
6. About a week later, lay the same variety of turf. Fill the cracks between the pieces of turf with some soil to which you have added a little sand, and keep the repair well-watered.

Comment: awesome, will get started on that. any concerns regarding doing this at the beginning of winter?

Comment: @Sam - None at all. Late autumn/ early winter is generally considered the best time of year to lay turf - although it takes longer to root, it requires no mowing, no fertilizing, very little watering (yours, of course, being in a covered area, will require a good deal more) and receives less traffic.

Answer (score 4):

Seeing as you have a warm-season grass, "[Sir Walter Buffalo Lawn](http://sirwalter.com.au/)", you may find the below answer here on SE of some interest:

- [Can my lawn be saved or is it time to dig it up and re-sod?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/can-my-lawn-be-saved-or-is-it-time-to-dig-it-up-and-re-sod/2021#2021)

The following example is one quote from that answer:

> Below I'm going to offer you both options, **starting anew** or **repair**, you can then decide which way you want to go.
>
> **Regardless which option you go with:**
>
> - The vast majority of the work should be carried out mid Spring to very! early Summer (the closer to mid Spring the better IMHO).

Also the below article may prove helpful:

- [Establishing a Warm Season Lawn](http://extension.missouri.edu/extensioninfonet/article.asp?id=1053)

---

Additionally you may find [this answer](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/whats-an-organic-way-to-discourage-crabgrass-from-a-large-lawn/1391#1391) somewhat useful, though it deals with cool-season lawns, the "general" fundamentals hold true...

The following example is one quote from that answer:

> - Around "Labor Day" here in the US, I prepare any bare spots for reseeding. Reseed using an appropriate seed for my lawn type. Cover the whole lawn with ½ to 1 inch (12.5 to 25mm) thick layer of STA-certified compost (bought in bulk locally). Water as needed, ie Amount needed for good germination to take place.

---

The below couple of "lawn dethatch" questions here on SE might prove helpful/useful:

- [Lawn Dethatching tools](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/1351/394)
- [How to tell if my lawn needs to be dethatched?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/q/902/394)