# Is early November too late in the season to overseed, repair a cool-season lawn?

Tags: weed-control, lawn, grass, lawn-repair

I'm wondering if it would be too late in the season to overseed, repair a cool-season lawn in preparation for the coming Spring.

I live in Atlantic Canada.

I've been fighting with our lawn since we purchased our place. The majority of it is weeds, I have no experience with this and am really at a loss of where to start without just starting from scratch.

Edit: Adding photos.
[image: Front lawn]
[image: Front lawn close-up 1]
[image: Front lawn close-up 2]
[image: Back lawn]
[image: Back lawn close-up]

Comment: Do you know what type of grass makes up your lawn? Have a read of **[this](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1390/whats-an-organic-way-to-discourage-crabgrass-from-a-large-lawn/1391#1391)** & see if it helps. Also read **[this](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/can-my-lawn-be-saved-or-is-it-time-to-dig-it-up-and-re-sod/2021#2021)**, keep in mind the information applies to a warm-season lawn, then let me know if you want me to write up similar information for a cool-season lawn...

Comment: What is the weather like there at the moment? And what will it be like for the next couple of months? When does Winter (weather) really kick-in?

Comment: Photos added to original post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Starting in spring might be a better idea if you are looking for a quick result. If you reseed in the fall many of the seeds will remain dormant until spring, letting weeds sprout. If you wait until it warms up in spring, the seeds will quickly sprout and fill in.

Comment: **[From here](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/2546/will-leveling-uneven-lawns-with-extra-sand-kill-future-lawns/2548#2548):** On the other hand, if you plan to establish a cool-season lawn via sowing seed, I can't recommend strongly enough that this should be carried out in late-Summer to early-Autumn (Fall). Doing so will greatly increase the success rate of establishing a strong, healthy lawn. Sowing cool-season lawn seed in Spring really is a lottery if it will survive or not, especially if the Summer is hot and dry... *<-- Just my personal opinion.*

Comment: IMO, the answer would be better if it gave temperature/precipitation ranges in which a new lawn fares best. @binarymelon can correct me if I'm wrong, but I'm presuming that summer in Atlantic Canada is relatively short and cool and winters are rather mild. If this is true, and precip is consistent year-round, then it might not matter when the lawn gets started. (Winter days are much shorter at high latitudes, though.)

Comment: This year was probably a bad example because we had a very cool Summer, but here is some historical temperature info for the region.
[May 2011](http://goo.gl/obGxJ)
[June 2011](http://goo.gl/itUKo)
[July 2011](http://goo.gl/Uztrw)
[August 2011](http://goo.gl/rZEiP)
[September 2011](http://goo.gl/6yvXy)