# What to do about fungus in lawn?

Tags: lawn, fungus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I be concerned about mushrooms in my lawn?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1529/should-i-be-concerned-about-mushrooms-in-my-lawn)

Every time I mow my lawn, I find a few of these bulbs of fungus.

[image]

Sometimes they are brown like in the picture I took and sometimes they are more white and smooth looking.  I usually just scoop them up and throw them away.  When I manipulate them they generally throw a bunch of "dust" around which I assume are spoors that are spreading them potentially.  They are always on one side of the house which I'm guessing has some decaying matter in it due to a neighbor's pear tree.  Other than getting rid of the pears when I see them, is there anything I can do to stop these things from growing?  Are they particularly dangerous to the lawn?  Are they going to keep spreading?  And what the heck are they anyways?

Comment: Those "bulbs of fungus" are mushrooms and this has been answered in [Should I be concerned about mushrooms in my lawn?](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/1529/should-i-be-concerned-about-mushrooms-in-my-lawn). This will be closed as a duplicate of that.

Comment: Thanks @yoda.  I read through that question and wasn't sure if these things were a different beast than regular mushrooms.  If the answers from that other question are appropriate than please mark as a duplicate.